# How do I execute any command editing its file (argument) "in place" using bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, sorting

I have a file temp.txt, that I want to sort with the `sort` command in bash.

I want the sorted results to replace the original file.

This doesn't work for example (I get an empty file):

```
sortx temp.txt > temp.txt
```

Can this be done in one line without resorting to copying to temporary files?

---

EDIT: The `-o` option is very cool for `sort`. I used `sort` in my question as an example. I run into the same problem with other commands:

```
uniq temp.txt > temp.txt.
```

Is there a better general solution?

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/a/547331/313521

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
sort temp.txt -o temp.txt
```

Comment: This is an answer. I was actually wondering if there is a generic solution to this problem. For example if I want to find all UNIQ lines in a file "in place", I can't do -o

Comment: It's not generic, but you can use -u with GNU sort to find unique lines

Comment: Has anyone solved the problem to allow e.g. `sort --inplace *.txt`? That would be crazy cool

Comment: @sehe Try this: `find . -name \*.txt -exec sort {} -o {} \;`

Comment: To type filename only once, brace expansion can be used: `sort -o temp.txt{,}`

Answer (score 29):

A `sort` needs to see all input before it can start to output. For this reason, the `sort` program can easily offer an option to modify a file in-place:

```
sort temp.txt -o temp.txt
```

Specifically, the [documentation of GNU `sort`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) says:

> Normally, sort reads all input before opening output-file, so you can safely sort a file in place by using commands like `sort -o F F` and `cat F | sort -o F`. However, `sort` with `--merge` (`-m`) can open the output file before reading all input, so a command like `cat F | sort -m -o F - G` is not safe as sort might start writing `F` before `cat` is done reading it.

While the documentation of BSD `sort` says:

> If [the] output-file  is one of the input files, sort copies it to a temporary file before sorting and writing the output to [the] output-file.

Commands such as `uniq` can start writing output before they finish reading the input. These commands typically do not support in-place editing (and it would be harder for them to support this feature).

You typically work around this with a temporary file, or if you absolutely want to avoid having an intermediate file, you could use a buffer to store the complete result before writing it out. For example, with `perl`:

```
uniq temp.txt | perl -e 'undef $/; $_ = <>; open(OUT,">temp.txt"); print OUT;'
```

Here, the perl part reads the complete output from `uniq` in variable `$_` and then overwrites the original file with this data. You could do the same in the scripting language of your choice, perhaps even in Bash. But note that it will need enough memory to store the entire file, this is not advisable when working with large files.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a more general approach, works with uniq, sort and whatnot.

```
{ rm file && uniq > file; } < file
```

Comment: Another generic approach, with `sponge` from the moreutils: `cat file |frobnicate |sponge file`.

Comment: @Tobu: why not submit that as a separate answer?

Comment: It's probably good to note that this doesn't necessarily preserve the files permissions. Your umask dictates what the new permissions will be.

Comment: Tricky one. Can you explain how does it exactly works?

Comment: @patryk.beza: In order: The input FD is opened from the original file; the original directory entry is deleted; the redirection is processed, creating a new empty file with the same name the old one used to have; then the command runs.

Comment: Is it possible for the contents of file to be overwritten with another file while it is being read (because its directory entry is deleted at the start of the operation)?

Comment: The directory entry is removed, but the underlying inode is not reused while there is an open file handle to it. `file` in the input redirection does not refer to the same inode as `file` in the output redirection.

Comment: In some cases `rm file` will ask for confirmation and interpret first line of `< file` as one, so `uniq` will receive file without that first line and you will lose it. Use `rm -f` to make sure `rm` won't ask for confirmation.

Comment: Also, `()` can be used instead of `{}`, and `;` after `uniq > file` does not seem to be required. To not type filename or path 3 times, I like to do it this way: `(f="file"; (rm -f "$f" && uniq > "$f") < "$f")` — so you only type it once.

Answer (score 11):

[Tobu's comment on sponge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4413942/1175459) warrants being an answer in its own right.

To quote from the [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) homepage:

> Probably the most general purpose tool in moreutils so far is sponge(1), which lets you do things like this:
>
> ```
> % sed "s/root/toor/" /etc/passwd | grep -v joey | sponge /etc/passwd
> ```

However, `sponge` suffers from the same problem [Steve Jessop comments on here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/146445/1175459) If any of the commands in the pipeline before `sponge` fail, then the original file will be written over.

```
$ mistyped_command my-important-file | sponge my-important-file
mistyped-command: command not found
```

Uh-oh, `my-important-file` is gone.

Comment: Sponge knows that it will be used to replace the input file and it initially creates a temp file to avoid a race condition.  In order for this to work, sponge must be the last element in the pipeline and it must be allowed to create the output file itself (as opposed to shell-level output redirection, for example).  BTW: It seems like an easy source-code fix for the 'fail' case would be to not rename the temp file in the case of a pipefail (don't know why sponge doesn't have that option).

Comment: I think if you add `set -o pipefail` at the beginning of your script, the error on `mistyped_command my-important-file` would make the script exit immediately, before executing `sponge`, thus preserving the important file.

Answer (score 7):

Here you go, one line:

```
sort temp.txt > temp.txt.sort && mv temp.txt.sort temp.txt
```

Technically there's no copying to a temporary file, and the 'mv' command should be instant.

Comment: Hm. I'd still call temp.txt.sort a temporary file.

Comment: But it's not making any unnecessary copies: it reads the input data once, and it writes the result once. So it may be a temporary file, but it's not copying to a temporary file (which is what he wanted to avoid)

Comment: This code is risky, because if sort fails for whatever reason without completing its job, the original is overwritten.

Comment: Lack of disk space being a plausible cause, or a signal (user hits CTRL-C).

Comment: if you want to use something like this use && (logical and) instead of ; because using that will make sure that if a command fails next one will not be executed. for example: cp backup.tar /root/backup.tar && rm backup.tar if you don't have rights to copy you'll be safe as the file won't be deleted

Comment: changed my answer to take your suggestions into account, thanks

Comment: + I'd rather avoid using this on a process run as root: this is a [race condition](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/avoid-race.html#TEMPORARY-FILES), that is an attacker could change the contents of the temporary file between the `sort` and the `mv` if he somehow got write access to that file.

Comment: This will also replace file permissions on temp.txt.

Comment: Another caveat whenever a temporary file is involved to make sure the naming of temporary to be unique. It could overwrite an existing file, so make sure either to not use temporary file or use it with care that there is no name clash (especially inside scripts).

Answer (score 5):

I like the `sort file -o file` answer but don't want to type the same file name twice.

Using BASH [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction):

```
$ sort file -o !#^
```

grabs the current line's first arg when you press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

A unique sort in-place:

```
$ sort -u -o file !#$
```

grabs the last arg in the current line.

Answer (score 4):

Many have mentioned the **-o** option. Here is the man page part.

From the man page:

```
   -o output-file
          Write output to output-file instead of to the  standard  output.
          If  output-file  is  one of the input files, sort copies it to a
          temporary file before sorting and writing the output to  output-
          file.
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be highly memory constrained, but you could use awk to store the intermediate data in memory, and then write it back out.

```
uniq temp.txt | awk '{line[i++] = $0}END{for(j=0;j<i;j++){print line[j]}}' > temp.txt
```

Comment: I think it’s [possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752174/reading-and-writing-a-file-tee-command/752451#752451) the `>` truncates the file before the command (`uniq` in this case) reads it.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `sponge` with the more common `sed`:

```
sed -ni r<(command file) file
```

It works for any command (`sort`, `uniq`, `tac`, ...) and uses the very well known `sed`'s [`-i` option](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62h) (edit files in-place).

**Warning:** Try `command file` first because editing files in-place is not safe by nature.

---

#### Explanation

Firstly, you're telling `sed` not to print the (original) lines ([`-n` option](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-15)), and with the help of the `sed`'s [`r` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37) and `bash`'s [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), the generated content by `<(command file)` will be the output saved **in place**.

---

#### Making things even easier

You can wrap this solution into a function:

```
ip_cmd() { # in place command
    CMD=${1:?You must specify a command}
    FILE=${2:?You must specify a file}
    sed -ni r<("$CMD" "$FILE") "$FILE"
}
```

---

#### Example

```
$ cat file
d
b
c
b
a

$ ip_cmd sort file
$ cat file
a
b
b
c
d

$ ip_cmd uniq file
$ cat file
a
b
c
d

$ ip_cmd tac file
$ cat file
d
c
b
a

$ ip_cmd
bash: 1: You must specify a command
$ ip_cmd uniq
bash: 2: You must specify a file
```

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the non-interactive editor, [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

Comment: heh -- that's a totally evil idea.  I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the argument `--output=` or `-o`

Just tried on FreeBSD:

```
sort temp.txt -otemp.txt
```

Comment: Though correct, it's simply a duplicate of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/146473/4095830)

Answer (score 1):

To add the `uniq` capability, what are the downsides to:

```
sort inputfile | uniq | sort -o inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the `sort` program, you have to use a intermediate file -- I don't think `sort` has an option for sorting in memory. Any other trick with stdin/stdout will fail unless you can guarantee that the buffer size for sort's stdin is big enough to fit the entire file.

Edit: shame on me. `sort temp.txt -o temp.txt` works excellent.

Comment: I read the Q also as being "in-place" but the second read made me believe he wasn't really asking for it

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
uniq file 1<> file
```

Comment: It should be noted though that the `<>` trick only works in this case because `uniq` is special in that it only copies input lines to output lines, dropping some on the way. If other command (e.g. `sed`) was used which would change the input (e.g. would change every `a` into `aa`), then it can override `file` in ways which don't make any sense and even loop infinitely, providing that the input is sufficiently large (more than a single read buffer).