# how to sort file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, sorting

This is my file content.

```
Receivables=Por cobrar
Payables=Cuentos por pagar 
ytdPurchases.label=Purchases YTD
validationError.maxValue=Value is too large, maximum value allowed is {0}
```

i want to sort this content in alphabetic order ...
how may i do that ??

Update:
This code will sort my file.

```
new_array = File.readlines("#{$base_properties}").sort
File.open("#{$base_properties}","w") do |file|
  new_array.each {|n| file.puts(n)}
end
```

Is there a better way to sort file?

Comment: Explain what you mean by _better_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obvious simplification:

```
new_array = File.readlines("#{$base_properties}").sort
File.open("#{$base_properties}","w") do |file|
  file.puts new_array
end
```

I'd just define a method like this, doing the opposite of `File.read`. It's highly reusable, and really should be part of the standard:

```
def File.write!(path, contents)
  File.open(path, "w"){|fh| fh.write contents}
end
```

And then sorting becomes:

```
File.write!($base_properties, File.readlines($base_properties).sort.join)
```

Answer (score 17):

Assuming your file is called "abc"

```
`sort abc -o abc`
```

Ruby shouldn't be used as a golden hammer. By using the command `sort` it will be much faster.

Comment: `strace` suggests that it works, but is it actually guaranteed that `abc` won't be overwritten too early as it would be with `sort <abc >abc` ?

Comment: @taw: If I was to design it, I would sort the file and then output it to the file, so no unintended overwriting would happen. I think the people who design these commands are smarter than I and have thought of this already.

Comment: Your belief in sanity of Unix commands is charmingly naive. I've seen enough to distrust them all instinctively ;-)

Comment: I'd like to think they got this one right ;) How hard could it be to stuff up sorting?

Comment: @taw if you're worried about the command working correctly you can always do `sort abc -o xyz`  :-)

Comment: this makes your code unix dependent, i would not use it on a portable application

Comment: @taw: It's not possible to sort a file if you have not read the whole things. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/147826/1403885 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open("out.txt", "w") do |file|
  File.readlines("in.txt").sort.each do |line|
    file.write(line.chomp<<"\n")
  end
end
```

Comment: can i sort file without using two files ?

Comment: sure: `a = File.readlines("in.txt").sort` creates array `a` containing the sorted lines.  then you can do anything you want with the results.