# Why piping to the same file doesn't work on some platforms?

Tags: bash, pipeline, overwrite, io-redirection, in-place

In cygwin, the following code works fine

```
$ cat junk
bat
bat
bat

$ cat junk | sort -k1,1 |tr 'b' 'z' > junk

$ cat junk
zat
zat
zat
```

But in the linux shell(GNU/Linux), it seems that overwriting doesn't work

```
[41] othershell: cat junk
cat
cat
cat
[42] othershell: cat junk |sort -k1,1 |tr 'c' 'z'
zat
zat
zat
[43] othershell: cat junk |sort -k1,1 |tr 'c' 'z' > junk
[44] othershell: cat junk
```

Both environments run BASH.

I am asking this because sometimes after I do text manipulation, because of this caveat, I am forced to make the tmp file. But I know in Perl, you can give "i" flag to overwrite the original file after some operations/manipulations. I just want to ask if there is any foolproof method in unix pipeline to overwrite the file that I am not aware of.

Comment: Perl's and `sed`'s `-i` perform the temporary file manipulation behind the scenes.

Comment: See [Bash: Is it ok to use same input file as output of a piped command?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3055005/95735)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general this can be expected to break.  The processes in a pipeline are all started up in parallel, so the `> junk` at the end of the line will usually truncate your input file before the process at the head of the pipelining has finished (or even started) reading from it.

Even if bash under Cygwin let's you get away with this you shouldn't rely on it. The general solution is to redirect to a temporary file and then rename it when the pipeline is complete.

Answer (score 9):

Four main points here:

1. "Useless use of *cat*." Don't do that.
2. You're not actually sorting anything with *sort*. Don't do that.
3. Your pipeline doesn't say what you think it does. Don't do that.
4. You're trying to over-write a file in-place while reading from it. Don't do that.

One of the reasons you are getting inconsistent behavior is that you are piping to a process that has redirection, rather than redirecting the output of the pipeline as a whole. The difference is subtle, but important.

What you want is to create a compound command with [Command Grouping](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping), so that you can redirect the input and output of the whole pipeline. In your case, this should work properly:

```
{ sort -k1,1 | tr 'c' 'z'; } < junk > sorted_junk
```

Please note that without anything to sort, you might as well skip the *sort* command too. Then your command can be run without the need for command grouping:

```
tr 'c' 'z' < junk > sorted_junk
```

Keep redirections and pipelines as simple as possible. It makes debugging your scripts much easier.

However, if you still want to abuse the pipeline for some reason, you could use the *sponge* utility from the **moreutils** package. The man page says:

> sponge  reads  standard  input and writes it out to the specified
>   file. Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input  before 
>   opening the  output file. This allows constricting pipelines that read
>   from and write to the same file.

So, your original command line can be re-written like this:

```
cat junk | sort -k1,1 | tr 'c' 'z' | sponge junk
```

and since junk will not be overwritten until sponge receives EOF from the pipeline, you will get the results you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer! I changed the input just to make my question clear. The original input needed to be sorted. But you are right. sort doesn't do anything in this example

Comment: `sponge` is just like `cat`

Comment: @nobar They are not the same. See the [sponge(1) man page](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/sponge/) from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

Comment: @CodeGnome: Sorry I did not intend to post that.  It was only the start of a sentence that I never completed.  Instead I wrote a usage note about `sponge` over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17491611/86967).

Answer (score 3):

You want to edit that file, you can just use the editor.

```
ex junk << EOF
%!(sort -k1,1 |tr 'b' 'z')
x
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the same file in pipeline is not advice, because when you do the mistake you can't get it back (unless you've the backup or it's the under version control).

This happens, because the input and output in pipeline is automatically buffered (which gives you an impression it works), but it actually it's running in parallel. Different platforms could buffer the output in different way (based on the settings), so on some you end up with empty file (because the file would be created at the start), on some other with half-finished file.

The solution is to use some method when the file is only overridden when it encounters an EOF with full buffered and processed input.

This can be achieved by:

- Using utility which can soaks up all its input before opening the output file.

  This can either be done by `sponge` (as opposite of `unbuffer` from `expect` package).
- Avoid using I/O redirection syntax (which can create the empty file before starting the command).

  For example using `tee` (which buffers its standard streams), for example:

  ```
  cat junk | sort | tee junk
  ```

  This would only work with `sort`, because it expects all the input to process the sorting. So if your command doesn't use `sort`, add one.

  Another tool which can be used is `stdbuf` which modifies buffering operations for its standard streams where you can specify the buffer size.
- Use text processor which can edit files in-place (such as `sed` or `ex`).

  Example:

  ```
  $ ex -s +'%!sort -k1' -cxa myfile.txt
  $ sed -i '' s/foo/bar/g myfile.txt
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following simple script, you can make it work like you want to:

```
$ cat junk | sort -k1,1 |tr 'b' 'z' | overwrite_file.sh junk
```

#### overwrite_file.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUT=$(cat -)

FILENAME="$*"

echo "$OUT" | tee "$FILENAME"
```

Note that if you don't want the updated file to be send to stdout, you can use this approach instead

#### overwrite_file_no_output.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUT=$(cat -)

FILENAME="$*"

echo "$OUT" > "$FILENAME"
```