# Stream and transform a file in place with nodejs

Tags: node.js, io, stream

I'd like to do something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var through = require('through');

var file = 'path/to/file.json';

var input = fs.createReadStream(file, 'utf8');
var output = fs.createWriteStream(file, 'utf8');

var buf = '';
input
.pipe(through(function data(chunk) { buf += chunk; }, function end() {
  var data = JSON.parse(buf);
  // Do some transformation on the obj, and then...
  this.queue(JSON.stringify(data, null, ' '));
})
.pipe(output);
```

But this fails because it's trying to read and write to the same destination. There are ways around it, like only piping to `output` from within the `end` callback above.

Is there a better way? By better, I mean uses less code or less memory. And yes, I'm aware that I could just do:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'path/to/file.json';

var str = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
var data = JSON.parse(str);    
// Do some transformation on the obj, and then...
fs.writeFileSync(file, JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '), 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way that your code will use *less* memory, because you need the whole file to parse it into a Javascript object. In this way, both versions of your code are equivalent memory-wise. If you can do some work without having to work on the full JSON object, check out [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream).

In your example, you *should* read the file, then parse and transform it, then write the result to a file; although you shouldn't use the synchronous version of the functions, see [the end of this paragraph of the Node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system):

> In busy processes, the programmer is strongly encouraged to use the asynchronous versions of these calls. The synchronous versions will block the entire process until they complete--halting all connections.

---

Anyway, I don't think you can read from a file while you're overwriting it. See [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586706/2137601) to the same problem.

Comment: While I agree that the synchronous versions should be avoided, in this example they resulted in drastically less code for a quick and temporary build step (not a long-running server process). Thanks for the link to the bash answer, it was helpful!

Comment: Indeed. Could you show us the content of the input file and the kind of transformation you wish to achieve? Without this, it's hard to know  if the algorithm is streamable or not.

Comment: The content was a really simple JSON file, `{ "key": "value", "someKeyToDelete": { "yep": "i won't be there" } }`, where I was just deleting `someKeyToDelete` from it.

Comment: I've found that I can use streams to overwrite a file I'm reading, but not reliably--sometimes it will work fine, and other times I end up with an empty file. Better to write to a temporary file, and then delete the original and rename the temp file over it.