# Bash- why can't a file be overwritten without the use of a temp file?

Tags: bash, overwrite

The standard procedure for overwriting a file is usually the following:

```
awk '{print $2*3}' file > tmp file
tmpFile > file
```

However, sometimes this poses to be a bit of a hassle because then one must remove the temp file after it is no longer being used.

So, why is it not possible to do this in the following way (without the need of a temp file) :

```
awk '{print $2*3}' file > file
```

The reason I ask is because I know that it is possible to append to a file as so:

```
awk '{print $2*3}' file >> file
```

So if appending a file, using `>>` as shown above, works fine, why can't one overwrite a file in the same way. Why are the two commands so different?

Moreover, does there exist a way of bypassing the need for a temp file (perhaps in a fashion similar to the 2nd excerpt), or is the first excerpt the only way?

*NOTE: the awk command is irrelevant, it can be replaced by any other command*

Comment: See [*this*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place)

Comment: possible duplicate of [After pipes, how to overwrite the original file? why does it work some some platform and doesnt in others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586623/after-pipes-how-to-overwrite-the-original-file-why-does-it-work-some-some-plat)

Comment: @tripleee you're right it is a duplicate, but I didn't know that when I formulated the question. Thanks for the down vote anyways. I flagged it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a temp file is a good idea because you can never be sure if the entire file will be read into memory. If you try to write it before it was read, then you might get a different result than you might have expected.

When using append, the command always goes through the entire file before adding new content, so there never remains a part of the file to be read.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a great idea (trying to read & write to same file), but if you insist on doing it, you could use the `<>` operator.

```
gawk '{print $2*3}' -- <> file
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for everything. You can use `sponge`.

```
awk '{print $2*3}' file | sponge file
```

You can get it from the moreutils package. The man page reads:

```
NAME
       sponge - soak up standard input and write to a file

SYNOPSIS
       sed '...' file | grep '...' | sponge [-a] file

DESCRIPTION
       sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
       Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before writing the
       output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and write
       to the same file.

       sponge preserves the permissions of the output file if it already exists.

       When possible, sponge creates or updates the output file atomically by
       renaming a temp file into place. (This cannot be done if TMPDIR is not in
       the same filesystem.)

       If the output file is a special file or symlink, the data will be written
       to it, non-atomically.

       If no file is specified, sponge outputs to stdout.

OPTIONS
       -a
           Replace the file with a new file that contains the file's original
           content, with the standard input appended to it. This is done
           atomically when possible.

AUTHOR
       Colin Watson and Tollef Fog Heen
```

Answer (score 0):

if u happen to be on a `mac`, you can emulate a `copy & paste` operation to do in-place edits *indirectly* without a temp file :

> ```
> awk '{ . . . }' file | LC_ALL=C pbcopy ; LC_ALL=C pbpaste > file
> ```

dunno what the equivalent commands are for `linux` or other platforms. avoid this if your file is over `500 MB` in size

you can also use this for `perl` or `python` etc since `"pasteboard copy"` is simply reading in contents via `/dev/stdin`.

*this is only a convenience shortcut and doesn't guarantee atomic ops whatsoever.*