# How to remove duplicates from a file and write to the same file?

Tags: bash, file, sorting, duplicates, in-place

I know my title is not much self-explanatory but let me try to explain it here.

I have a file name `test.txt` which has some duplicate lines. Now, what I want to do is remove those duplicate lines and at the same time `update test.txt` with the new content.

**test.txt**

```
AAAA
BBBB
AAAA
CCCC
```

I know I can use `sort -u test.txt` to remove the duplicates but to update the file with new content how do I redirect it's output to the same file. The below command doesn't work.

```
sort -u test.txt > test.txt
```

So, why the above command is not working and whats the correct way?

Also is there any other way like

```
sort_and_update_file test.txt
```

which sorts and automatically updates my file without any need of redirection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a file in place using bash shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146435/how-do-i-sort-a-file-in-place-using-bash-shell)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sort -u -o test.txt test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why I was not able to use redirection with sort.

Answer (score 5):

Redirection in the shell will not work as you are trying to read and write from the same file at the same time.  Actually the file is opened for writing (`> file.txt`) before the sort is even executed

@potong's answer works because the sort program itself probably stores all lines in memory, I would not rely on it because it does not explicitly specifies in the manpage that it CAN be the same as the input file (though it will likely work).   Unless documented to work "in place" I would not do it (@perreal's answer would work, or you can store intermediate results in shell memory)

Comment: Any `sort` can only output anything at all after *all* entries to be sorted are known to the algorithm -- this is true regardless of the algorithm used. This means the output from `sort` will only be given when it is no longer necessary to read from `test.txt`, so I would say it is *per definition* safe to output to the same file...

Comment: @rody_o, you cant conceive a sort that operates on disk?  what did they do before there was ''infinite memory'' ?   Is there no way to sort on disk?  I just do not assume to kno how something is implemented, if it is documented to support 'in place' or specifically allows the same file, then I trust it otherwise, I would rather err on the safe side.

Comment: Yes, come to think of it...sorting huge files MUST be done on disk, my bad. I half-assumed small files would be read *once* and the algorithm executed from memory....So `sort -o` must then make a little over 2N writes to `test.txt`, assuming it contains N lines, correct?

Comment: @rody_o from a complexity perspective O(N)==O(2N), so 2N would actually not be that bad, but does imply that you cannot use the same file...   That said, discussion of sort complexity is way out out scope of this discussion  (and I am rusty, havnt doe that since college), but I would assume its way worse ...

Comment: @nhed: what you're talking about is called "external sorting"; Wikipedia has a [good article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

Answer (score 4):

#### Use Sponge for Reading/Writing to Same File

You can use the *sponge* utility from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) to soak up standard output before writing the file. This prevents you from having to shuffle files around, and approximates an in-place edit. For example:

```
sort -u test.txt | sponge test.txt
```

#### Sample Output

Using your corpus, this results in the expected output.

```
$ cat test.txt 
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

Answer (score 2):

this is not as inefficient as it looks:

```
sort -u test.txt > test.txt.tmp && mv test.txt.tmp test.txt
```

Comment: It may not be insufficient but the @potong's answer is much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: This is the canonical answer to this question. Safe, portable, simple and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vim for editing file in-place:

```
$ ex -s +'%!sort' -cxa test.txt
```

Multiple files:

```
$ ex -s +'bufdo!%!sort' -cxa *.*
```