# How do I update a file using commands run against the same file?

Tags: linux, shell, command, pipe, in-place

As an easy example, consider the following command:

```
$ sort file.txt
```

This will output the file's data in sorted order.  How do I put that data right back into the same file?  I want to update the file with the sorted results.

**This is not the solution:**

```
$ sort file.txt > file.txt
```

... as it will cause the file to come out blank.  Is there a way to update this file without creating a temporary file?

Sure, I could do something like this:

```
sort file.txt > temp.txt; mv temp.txt file.txt
```

But I would rather keep the results in memory until processing is done, and then write them back to the same file.  sort actually has a flag that will allow this to be possible:

```
sort file.txt -o file.txt
```

...but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on the binary having a special flag to account for this, as not all are guaranteed to.  Is there some kind of linux command that will hold the data until the processing is finished?

Comment: You do know that `mv` is really rename, right? The advantage of the use of a temporary file is that it does not lead to problems when your machine crashes in the middle of the `sort` (for example).

Comment: @rici Yes, mv overwrites the file for me.  This simulates updating the file. Regardless, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require an intermediary file.

Comment: `mv` doesn't overwrite the file. It just renames it. Of course, it is true that there is a moment during which both files exist at the same time, but on the assumption that the data could fit into memory, that's probably not much of a load on your disk. In fact, many utilities (including sed) which claim to work "in-place" actually use a temporary file, both for safety and for simplicity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I execute any command editing its file (argument) "in place" using bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146435/how-do-i-execute-any-command-editing-its-file-argument-in-place-using-bash)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicates from a file and write to the same file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375426/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-file-and-write-to-the-same-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sort, you can use the `-o` option.

For a more general solution, you can use `sponge`, from the moreutils package:

```
sort file.txt | sponge file.txt
```

As mentioned below, error handling here is tricky. You may end up with an empty file if something goes wrong in the steps before `sponge`.

This is a duplicate of this question, which discusses the solutions above: [How do I execute any command editing its file (argument) "in place" using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146435/how-do-i-sort-a-file-in-place-using-bash-shell/146445#146445)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice sort had a flag to handle this as well.  I'm still looking for a solution that work with programs that don't have these special flags to account for rewriting to the same file.

Comment: @TrevorHickey - Try the sponge solution provided in the question -- it should do what you're looking for.
Basically, operate on the file, pipe the output to `sponge file` and you're done.

Comment: `sort file.txt | sponge file.txt`

Comment: @angie: [edit] your answer and add `sponge` there. Note: if there is an error the input file may be incomplete e.g., empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `sed` (with its [`r` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37)), and [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
sed -ni r<(sort file) file
```

In this way, you're telling `sed` not to print the (original) lines ([`-n` option](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-15)) and to append the file generated by `<(sort file)`.
The well known [`-i` option](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62h) is the one which does the trick.

#### Example

```
$ cat file
b
d
c
a
e
$ sed -ni r<(sort file) file
$ cat file
a
b
c
d
e
```

Comment: +1 for a very creative use of `sed`.  Not everyone will want a backup file.  With GNU `sed`, unlike BSD `sed`, that can be accomplished by simply omitting  `.bak` from the command.

Answer (score 0):

Try vim-way:

```
$ ex -s +'%!sort' -cxa file.txt
```