# How to sort a text file numerically and then store the results in the same text file?

Tags: linux

I have tried `sort -n test.text > test.txt`.  However, this leaves me with an empty text file.  What is going on here and what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/146473/651848

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I execute any command editing its file (argument) "in place" using bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146435/how-do-i-execute-any-command-editing-its-file-argument-in-place-using-bash)

Answer (score 1):

Sort does not sort the file in-place. It outputs a sorted copy instead.

You need `sort -n -k 4 out.txt > sorted-out.txt`.

**Edit**: To get the order you want you have to sort the file with the numbers read in reverse. This does it:

```
cut -d' ' -f4 out.txt | rev | paste - out.txt | sort -k1 -n | cut -f2- > sorted-out.txt
```

For more learning -

```
sort -nk4 file
```

> -n for numerical sort
>
> -k for providing key
>
> or add -r option for reverse sorting

```
sort -nrk4 file
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are reading and writing to the same file. You can't do that. You can try something a temporary file, as `mktemp` or even something as:

```
sort -n test.text > test1.txt
mv test1.txt test
```

For `sort`, you can also do the following:

```
sort -n test.text -o test.text
```